# Adding focus to the current tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, dom-events, setstate

I am trying to open up a page in a new tab, but it always makes the newly opened tab active. I want the current tab to be active and the new page should open on a  background. I am trying to do it using a function without any `<a>` tag.

What I have tried:

```
navigate = () => {
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
    window.focus();
 }

<button onClick={this.navigate}>Navigate</button>
```

Comment: I think that is dependent on the browser and user settings, which you can't control. If you find a way.. plz update it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible as far as I know, that's controlled by the Browser and not by your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to open a new tab in the background from a web page.